Python: Relative import with no known parent package
I have an AWS Python lambda. The directory structure is as follows"
src
    __init__.py
    main.py
    service.py

I am initiating a detabase connection in __init__.py file and then importing the connection variable in main.py
from . import conn
I get the following error:

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.

I am new to Python and trying to get a hang of the imports. Shouldn't main.py have access to everything from __init__.py since they are in the same package called src

It depends on where the main script (the one with which the Python program is started) is located. This may be AWS lambda specific, so maybe add the appropriate tag.

How are you running main.py?

There are many Q&A about relative imports in Python out there. It can be a bit obscure if you don't know what you are doing. Since it was answered very often and in every level of detail I will make it short here. Just google your error and you'll find many explanations.
Just some keywords for you to search for: Important for the relative import mechanism is the global variable __package__ and the PYTHONPATH. In most cases in which you encounter this error you will find __package__ to be None.
Solution
I'm not sure about your setup with aws lambdas. But if its a normal project structure without fancy entry points you can try the following:
Create a parent package to wrap your modules in. Then make sure that this parent package is available from PYTHONPATH. In Pycharm e.g. you can achieve this by marking your src directory as "sources root". Additionally, you must ensure to call your script in a way that __package__ will be set. If you are doing it from command line, execute it as module i.e. python -m mypackage.main.whatever. In Pycharm, everything should work out of the box if you have marked it as "sources root".
